# Wordpress disable /admin redirect to /wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have my website built with `wordpress 4.5.2`.

For wordpress contro panel, it it normal to login with `myweb.com/wp-admin` directory. But I have another control panel with other application in the directory `myweb.com/admin`.

The problem is whenever I try to login to `myweb.com/admin` it redirects to `myweb.com/wp-admin`

How to disable it?

Comment: Did you try maybe installing simple 301 redirect?https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

Comment: @Tarson that is not working for me

Comment: Was it a recent change in WP update cause I was never able to just type in "admin"?

Answer (score 7):

You should cancel the default shortcuts in `function.php` :

```php
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000 );
```

---

From the docs:

[`wp_redirect_admin_locations()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect_admin_locations/):

> If a user visits example.com/admin, they’ll be redirected to /wp-admin. Visiting /login redirects to /wp-login.php, and so on.

Comment: For anyone else with the same question. This here is the correct answer. For reference see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect_admin_locations/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add below code in your `functions.php`

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

I hope this solution is work for you